# How to Change this 2nd Order System of Equations into a 1st Order System of Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was wondering how I'd go about changing this 2nd order system  into a 1st order system? I've attached my work so far but I don't know if it's correct.

Note: I'm pretty sure the sign() operator is there for the code that I'll be implementing the 1st order system in.

[image: Problem Statement]

$\Large{x''=\frac{-C_{d}x'sign(x')\sqrt{(y')^2+(x')^2}}{m}}$

$\Large{y''=-g + \frac{-C_{d}x'sign(x')\sqrt{(y')^2+(x')^2}}{m}}$

$\Large{Y_{1}= x'}$

$\Large{Y_{2}= y'}$

$\Large{Y_{1}'= x''=\frac{-C_{d}x'sign(x')\sqrt{(y')^2+(x')^2}}{m}}$

$\Large{Y_{2}'= y''=-g + \frac{-C_{d}x'sign(x')\sqrt{(y')^2+(x')^2}}{m}}$

$\Large{Y_{1}'= \frac{-C_{d}Y_{1}sign(Y_{1})\sqrt{(Y_{2})^2+(Y_{1})^2}}{m}}$

$\Large{Y_{2}'= -g+ \frac{-C_{d}Y_{2}sign(Y_{2})\sqrt{(Y_{2})^2+(Y_{1})^2}}{m}}$

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I'll try to edit it now so that it's in the format you've mentioned. Is the picture of the problem statement okay, or is there a better way?

Comment: Ahh! I didn't even notice! I'll fix that right away.

Comment: This is a strange situation. By using the term "rocket" one would expect some terms for the enduring propulsion, at least for some time. The equations without the signs are just the normal ballistic equations for a cannon ball or any other passively moving object. The sign in $x$ direction makes no sense at all, in $y$ direction it makes the friction add velocity on the way down.